# Extracting only required columns/data from Google Cloud Stackdriver logging

Tags: stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

Is there a way to extract only required columns/data from Stackdriver logging.

From stackdriver, I have extracted data with adding some filters to Google Cloud BigQuery but it became a table with large number of columns in which all columns are not required.